# Select a Master Page in Web Developer Express

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

The dialog box for adding a web form to a web project in Visual Studio has a checkbox to 'Select Master Page'. This checkbox doesn't exist in the Web Developer Express Edition. Is there a simple alternative to attach a Master Page while adding a new web form in the Express Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely building a web application project instead of a website project.

Website projects have the "select master page" checkbox option. Web application projects do not; instead you should:

1. Add new item
2. Select the "Web Content Form" template (instead of the Web Form template)
3. Select the master page to use